# Regex to find a word between $$ sign

Tags: java, regex

I want regular expression to find a word between $$ sign only. It must start and end with $ sign. I have tried below expression

```
final String regex = "\\$\\w+\\$";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("$abc$ cde$efg$hij pqr");
```

This should give me count as 1. But my regular expression also considering second occurrence of (cde$efg$hij) which it should not consider as it is not starting and ending with $$ sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use non-word boundaries:

```
final String regex = "\\B\\$\\w+\\$\\B";
```

The pattern will only match if the `$abc$` is not preceded and followed with word chars. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mYryKx/1).

See [Java demo](https://ideone.com/IRYNXi):

```
String regex = "\\B\\$\\w+\\$\\B";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("$abc$ cde$efg$hij pqr");
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
} // => $abc$
```

Besides non-word boundaries, you may use *whitespace boundaries* if you only want to match in between whitespace chars or start/end of string:

```
String regex = "(?<!\\S)\\$\\w+\\$(?!\\S)";
```

Or, use unambiguous word boundaries (as I call them):

```
String regex = "(?<!\\w)\\$\\w+\\$(?!\\w)";
```

The `(?<!\\w)` negative lookbehind will fail the match if a word char is found immediately to the left of the current location, and the `(?!\w)` negative lookahead will fail the match if a word char is found immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was extracting fields between dollar signs for me.

```
List<String> getFieldNames(@NotNull String str) {
    final String regex = "\\$(\\w+)\\$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    List<String> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    while (matcher.find()) {
        fields.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
    return fields;
}
```

This will return list of words between dollar signs.